# Is there an option to define in-text if an acronym description should printed in footnote?

Tags: glossaries

I defined different acronyms. For some of them that are not described in-text I want to print a short description in a footnote instead of the long format on first use. Is it possible with the glossaries package to specify this with an option like `\gls[long-footnote]{CUDA}` (pseudo code) for example?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newacronym{CD}{CD}{Compact Disk}
\newacronym{CUDA}{CUDA}{Compute Unified Device Architecture is a parallel computing platform and application programming interface (API) model created by NVIDIA} 

\begin{document}
\gls{CD}\\
\gls{CUDA}
\end{document}
```

Here the description/long form of CUDA should be printed in a footnote.

Comment: Your document misses `\makeglossaries` ;-).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In the MWE? Or do you indicate that I should print the long description in the glossary ;-)?

Comment: In the MWE... I don't understand your question however completely.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yeah I'm not quite sure about the best way to handle acronyms that I only use in a single section and that I want to introduce shortly in a footnote.

Comment: I think you should look after `footnote-desc` style (see page 160 etc. in the current manual `glossaries-user.pdf`)

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviation handling provided by `glossaries` doesn't allow for mixed abbreviation styles. (This is actually something I'm trying to address with the pending `glossaries-extra` package, which is currently only available for testing purposes on my [experimental code page](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/expl/).)

I think the only way to deal with this is to define the exception with `\newglossaryentry` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newacronym{CD}{CD}{Compact Disk}

\newglossaryentry{CUDA}{name=CUDA,
 description={Compute Unified Device Architecture is a
 parallel computing platform and application programming interface
 (API) model created by NVIDIA},
 first={CUDA\protect\footnote{\protect\glsentrydesc{CUDA}}}}

\begin{document}
First: \gls{CD}; \gls{CUDA}.

Next: \gls{CD}; \gls{CUDA}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting page]